# How to read data from an existing mongodb collection and display it on browser using node/express?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I have an existing database named 'mig' consisting of a collection named 'Employee',
I have tried the following code but it sends the data in raw json format to the browser upon opening localhost:3000

```
var express = require('express')
var assert = require('assert')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mig'
var app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(client => {
        const db = client.db('mig');
        const collection = db.collection('Employee');
        app.locals.collection = collection;
        app.listen(3000, () => console.log('REST API running on port 3000'));

        process.on('SIGINT', () => {
            client.close();
            process.exit();
        });

    }).catch(error => console.error(error));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const collection = req.app.locals.collection;
    collection.find({}).toArray().then
    (response => res.status(200).json(response)).catch(error => console.error(error));
})
```

I need to know how can I render this collection's data to the browser in a proper html format. I did search a lot for the past few days maybe the keywords got wrong  or something likely. Please help me with this issue.

**P.s.** - I don't know if I can use mongoose because the schema for the existing collection will be very difficult to define as it contains 10000 rows vs 1000 columns. Please try to provide me with a solution, that will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Neelabh sorry about posting a `Python` answer earlier. 
You can use `Mustache` or `Jade` Engines. 
Example for Jade [Jade to Table](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/jade-template-engine)

Jade table example:

```
    div
     table
      thead
        tr
          th Col1
          th Col2
          th Col3
      tbody
        each srec in places
         tr
          td #{srec.item}
          td #{srec.item_desc}
          td #{srec.status_value}
```

[Ref Link:](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=140777)

Note: You might want to reduce the number of columns (from 1000) to a fixed mandatory columns like 10-30. And have an option selector in UI to pick particular columns.

Comment: Yeah sure that is what my final aim is, to paginate the columns and rows. But I am not able to find a starting point as to where and how to include engines like Jade. Can you help me out?

Comment: Try generating your codebase through, [Express Generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). While generating the code use option `-v jade`. This will give you all the required components/directories/configs.

Comment: says jade has been renamed to pug!

Comment: True. From their Git Page `This project was formerly known as "Jade". However, it was revealed to us that "Jade" is a registered trademark; as a result, a rename was needed. After some discussion among the maintainers, "Pug" was chosen as the new name for this project. As of version 2, "pug" is the official package name.`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send html to the browser with your data interpolated inside you need to use a template engine.
[Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) and [EJS](https://ejs.co/) are good options compatible with `express` to help you get it done.

Using template engine you can insert the data from your database into the and html file before sending it to the browser.

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks, that might help. Can you provide with a more appropriate solution as to how?